# Correlation for Multiple Comparison within a study

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

We have:

- 2 treatment groups (A, B)
- 1 control group (C)
- sample size n is equal for all groups (A, B, C)
- correlation *r*_AB = 0
- correlation *r*_CC = 1

->The correlation of *r*_AC and *r*_BC is 0.5

**Questions:**

- Can anyone explain it, why is the correlation of *r*_AC and *r*_BC 0.5?
- And how can I precisely calculate the correlation of *r*_AC and *r*_BC with different sample size?

I appreciate your help.
Sorry for the missing subscripts. I do not know how to do it here. I could not copy paste it from word.